# How to add drop symbol to parent nav items which have child

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation

I have a navigation system like this:

[image]

As you can see I have two Parent Menus as "**Projects**" and **Plans** which they have some sub menus. Now when the result rendered I am getting a navbar like this:

[image]

which is not clear that the  "**Projects**" and **Plans** has sub menus. Now can you please let me know how I can style the navbar to dynamically add the drop down arrow to all navs which they have child (sub menus) like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each WP menu item that contains a submenu haves the "menu-item-has-children" class for `<li>` you can use that class for add a pointer for sub menu:

For example the simple example can be this but you can use that for creating better pointer for your site:

```
.menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after{
   content: "(have child)";
}
```